# Refining search results of Google Custom Search Engine

Tags: google-custom-search

We are using Custom Search Engine(CSE) of Google for getting search results in our website forum. It is working fine and we are able to get the results properly. For making the search easier, we have planned to provide advanced search options like sorting and filtering options in forum which is using Custom Search Engine to get the search result.

We would like to provide the below options for filtering.

- Filtering by category - Each forum comes under some category, need to filter the search result based on the category.
- Filtering by tags - Each forum has some tags, need to filter the search result based on the tags.

How can we achieve the above requirement using CSE of Google? If it’s not possible using CSE, is there any other different searching option to achieve this scenario?

Comment: Can anyone help me to get a suggestion?